# Magento2: Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

Tags: magento2, php-7.1

I have installed **Zend OPcache v7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1** on my ubuntu machine 
but on indexing command it shows error  **Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'**

please suggest
[image: pic1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like missing mcrypt

`sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt`

And

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```